# Correct way to handle exception handshake between python and oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am having the below proc that I am calling from Python , the issue is that I am not able to see the exception coming out of the block, for reproducing right now I have forced raise an exception but I am not able to see this in the Python side script

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mark_step
(
   batch_id   IN NUMBER
  ,request_id IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER IS


BEGIN
   INSERT INTO temp_log VALUES ('entered');
   RAISE no_data_found;

   return 0;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      INSERT INTO temp_log VALUES ('exception');

END mark_step;
```

The client script calling this function

```
l_result = cur.callfunc('mark_step', cx_Oracle.STRING,
                                    [batch_id,request_id])



print(l_result)
```

Comment: You are handling the Exception using `BEGIN.. EXCEPTION..END` block so I don't think that the exception will flow to the python script. Your exception block is handling it and there is issue of the return value also. in `exception` block there must be a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function gracefully handles the exception and Python script does not get any visibility of the function having failed add Raise on the Exception Block

```
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      INSERT INTO temp_log VALUES ('exception');
      RAISE;
END mark_step;
```

On the Python side you could add try , except blocks to explicitly handle the exception in case you are not doing that already

```
try:   
   l_result = cur.callfunc('credit_ref_mig.mark_step', cx_Oracle.STRING,
                                       [batch_id,request_id])

   print(l_result)
except as e:
   print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no issue except missing `return value` in the `exception block` in your code.

The `exception` which is raised by your `function` is handled by the `exception block` contained in the `function` itself.

see the demo as follows:

Creating the table

> ```
> SQL> CREATE TABLE TEMP_LOG (
>   2      LOG_   VARCHAR2(50)
>   3  );
>
> Table created.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Creating the `function`, see inline comments:

> ```
> SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MARK_STEP (
>   2      BATCH_ID     IN           NUMBER,
>   3      REQUEST_ID   IN           VARCHAR2
>   4  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
>   5  BEGIN
>   6      INSERT INTO TEMP_LOG VALUES ( 'entered' );
>   7      RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND; -- error raised by this statement will be handeled by following exception block
>   8      RETURN 0;
>   9  EXCEPTION
>  10      WHEN OTHERS THEN
>  11          INSERT INTO TEMP_LOG VALUES ( 'exception' );
>  12          RETURN -1; -- this is misssing in your code
>  13  END;
>  14  /
>
> Function created.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Calling the function:

> ```
> SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
> SQL>
> SQL> DECLARE
>   2      CNT   NUMBER;
>   3  BEGIN
>   4      CNT := MARK_STEP(1, 'v');
>   5      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('result := ' || CNT);
>   6      COMMIT;
>   7  END;
>   8  /
> result := -1
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Checking the data in the temp_log table:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT * FROM TEMP_LOG;
>
> LOG_
> --------------------------------------------------
> entered
> exception
>
> SQL>
> ```

See both the sections are executed and the result of the `function` was also `-1`.

Now, If you want to raise the error to the external calling program then you can remove the entire `exception block` as follows:

> ```
> SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MARK_STEP (
>   2      BATCH_ID     IN           NUMBER,
>   3      REQUEST_ID   IN           VARCHAR2
>   4  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
>   5  BEGIN
>   6      INSERT INTO TEMP_LOG VALUES ( 'entered' );
>   7
>   8      COMMIT; -- added commit to see if it is working or not
>   9      RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND; -- error raised by this statement will be handeled by following exception block
>  10      RETURN 0;
>  11  --EXCEPTION
>  12  --    WHEN OTHERS THEN
>  13  --        INSERT INTO TEMP_LOG VALUES ( 'exception' );
>  14  --        RETURN -1; -- this is misssing in your code
>  15  END;
>  16  /
>
> Function created.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Calling the updated `function` and checking the data in the `temp_log` table.

> ```
> SQL> TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_LOG;
>
> Table truncated.
>
> SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
> SQL>
> SQL> DECLARE
>   2      CNT   NUMBER;
>   3  BEGIN
>   4      CNT := MARK_STEP(1, 'v');
>   5      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('result := ' || CNT);
>   6      COMMIT;
>   7  END;
>   8  /
> DECLARE
> *
> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-01403: no data found
> ORA-06512: at "TEJASH.MARK_STEP", line 9
> ORA-06512: at line 4
>
>
> SQL> SELECT * FROM TEMP_LOG;
>
> LOG_
> --------------------------------------------------
> entered
>
> SQL>
> ```

See, the `error` is thrown now and all the code above the `raise exception` worked as expected.

I hope, you find this useful.

Cheers!!